# rails linking to nested resource with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, nested-resources

Action::Controller says the value of profile id is nil in the link_to method. This is my code:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<h2>Listing Schools</h2>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @schools.each do |school| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= school.name %></td>
        <td><%= link_to edit_user_profile_school_path(current_user, school) %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<%= link_to 'New School', new_school_path %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the key for your params:

```
<%= link_to edit_user_profile_school_path(profile_id: current_user.id, school_id: school.id) %>
```

assuming your route looks something like:

```
post 'users/:profile_id/schools/:school_id'
```

Hard to say for sure without seeing more code, but it looks like you're missing :profile_id in your params

Comment: Do I have to be so explicit? Here's the route      edit_user_profile_school GET    /users/:user_id/profile/schools/:id/edit(.:format)                  schools#edit

Comment: here's another link from my app but this one works     <%= link_to 'Profile', new_user_profile_path(current_user) %> you see the way i used current_user object instead of current_user.id there? that works ...

Comment: also you've mixed up the profile id with user id "profile_id: current_user.id,"